# Angular - $watch to check service state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS v1.4.8. I have defined the following service to keep what form user is editting right now:

```
  orderApp.service('editAddressService', function(){

    var currentEdit = '';
    return {
        getCurrentEdit: function(){
            return currentEdit;
        },
        setCurrentEdit: function(value){
            currentEdit = value;
        },
        clearCurrentEdit: function(){
            currentEdit = '';
        }
    }
});
```

Now I want to use this information in controller and be notified about any changes. So I wrote this function:

```
 orderApp.controller('AddressController', ['editAddressService', '$scope', function(editAddressService, $scope){

    var addressCtrl = this;

    addressCtrl.editMode = false;

    addressCtrl.toEditMode = function(){
        addressCtrl.beforeEdit = angular.copy(addressCtrl.address);
        addressCtrl.editMode = true;
        editAddressService.setCurrentEdit(addressCtrl.addressType);
        console.log("Check changes - "+editAddressService.getCurrentEdit());
    };

    ...

    //Check if user starts to edit another address widget. In this case
    //close current editing form
    $scope.$watch('editAddressService.getCurrentEdit()', function(newVal, oldVal){
        console.log("New value - "+newVal);
        console.log("My value - "+addressCtrl.addressType);

        if(addressCtrl.addressType !== newVal){
            addressCtrl.cancelEdit();
        }
    });

}]);
```

According to console output watch function is not executed when values change. Did I miss something?

Comment: string you passed to scope.$watch is evaluating in this scope. editAddressService is not known in this scope, so it is always undefined... Note: this code looks weird, really( You really need that service? Just store currentEdit in controller - this is what controller for. etc.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I have 2 address forms, each form uses AddressController. My goal is to allow user edit only one form at time - that's why I created "editAddressService" to keep a record of current editing form. Can you advice any other way to implement it without services?

Comment: this totally depends on what exactly you want: simplest case - just add this 'currentEdit'  to parent of AddressController's. For more advanced options you may want to use angular xeditable or implement your own editable same way. Anyway using service like that is not smart, at least I do not see any future for such code.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I will try to add "currentEdit" property to parent controller. It's not clear to me how I will call AddressController action from it's parent though. p.s. I started to learn angular week ago, so do not be surprised that code is weird :)

Comment: while it mostly makes sense what you are trying to accomplish here, this goes against the angular design. you are essentially breaking the two way binding that is at the core of angular.

Comment: @Claies I don't quite understand how $watch breaking the 2 way binding in this case. Can you explain it in more details?

Answer (score 0):

`$watch` can work with the results of a function call as well as a string:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
        return editAddressService.getCurrentEdit();
    }, function(newVal, oldVal){
        console.log("New value - "+newVal);
        console.log("My value - "+addressCtrl.addressType);

        if(addressCtrl.addressType !== newVal){
            addressCtrl.cancelEdit();
        }
});
```

Note that the function can and will be called often, so make sure that it does not mutate anything.